# php saving file to relative path

Tags: php, html, file, input, path

```
$target_dir = "../images/photos/";
```

Im trying to save a document to this file in ths folder, the code snippet im using to do this is:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file " . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) . " has been uploaded.";
```

and im getting the error is:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(../images/photos/flower.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\a\front\photos\upload.php on line 40

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php1474.tmp' to '../images/photos/flower.jpg' in C:\xampp\htdocs\a\front\photos\upload.php on line 40
Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.
```

I can really use some help on this ive been working on uploading pics and setting up this side of my webpage for 3 days. Im learning as i go and started learning python last year as my first coding langue, and then jumped right into html, css, php, and mysql

Comment: The folder im trying to save in is in the root directory and im working on a file 3 folders up

Comment: well it seems like it doesnt matter where the image is saved to i should just be happy its uploaded

Comment: Did you try creating `C:\xampp\htdocs\a\front\images\photos` folder first?

Comment: folder path is already there, i decided that it doesnt matter what folder the pics are going into they can still be accessed from any where,  so im good to go

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use backslashes (`\`) in your paths? It could be the cause of the missfunctioning. It's sometimes a kind of Windows/Linux/Mac uncompatibility.